# Can -c replace -que in other words than atque and neque?

Tags: grammar-choice, conjunction, enclitic

The enclitic *-que* in the words *neque* and *atque* can be shortened to produce *nec* and *ac*.
Are there other instances where *-que* can turn into *-c*?
Can this be productive, or can it only happen in very special cases?
(Bonus question: Are there examples where scansion suggests that *-que* must be read as *-c*?)

It seems that *ac* is only used before consonants in classical Latin, whereas *atque*, *nec* and *neque* could be used anywhere, but this is irrelevant here.

Comment: The question title is pretty different from the body: I think it's a pretty obvious *no* that -c cannot replace -que "in general." I would be surprised if there were even a couple more examples of this, much less a codified rule.

Comment: @brianpck Good point. I edited the title. I suspect that it cannot happen in general. My question is whether there is any amount of productivity or whether the phenomenon is found at all outside *ac* and *nec*.

Comment: I've seen a lot of these questions here: When the question is "are there more examples of this", and yet there are no more examples of this, what's a good answer? A simple "No, I haven't found any and no one mentions it"?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Questions of that kind are indeed tricky. I think "No, I looked up this and this source and no one that I remember mentions it" is a good answer. A very definitive negative answer is hard to give, but I am willing to accept a "no" and change my mind if someone comes with positive evidence later on. While "no" can be a good answer (and probably the correct one here), it does call for some justification.

Comment: @brianpck You commented first, you want the first go for the (tentative) negative answer?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Perhaps I was mistaken in my original answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a longish post attempting a negative answer, and as a last precaution consulted a list of [all Latin words ending in -c](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=c&lang=la). *One* word stuck out to me like a sore thumb, and further research indicates that it may, in fact, be a contraction of -que to -c:

> [dōnĕc](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddonec): conj. [shortened from ante- and post-class. form dōnĭcum , from old dative doni (dioni; for root, etc., v. dies) and conj. cum.... **—In the Inscr. of Orell. 4370 DONIQVIES is i. q. DONIQUE IS, and donique = donicum**

It appears, thus, that at least some authors saw *donec* as a contraction of *donique*. This helps with the parsing of Lucretius, *De Rerum Natura*, 2: 1116

> ...ignem ignes procudunt aetheraque aether,
>   **donique** ad extremum crescendi perfica finem
>   omnia perduxit rerum natura creatrix;

Leonard's translation:

> ...and fires, as on a forge,
>   Beat out new fire; and ether forges ether;
>   Till nature, author and ender of the world,
>   Hath led all things to extreme bound of growth

I will include my other answer, since I believe it otherwise helps shed some light on this:

---

It appears that this kind of substitution of -c for -que is only present in these two conjunctions:

- atque: ac
- neque: nec

It is difficult to prove a negative, and I am willing to be corrected, but one fairly convincing inductive line of reasoning would be to choose similar words (i.e. conjunctions with "que") and check if a similar substitution is attested. Here's a list of such words from a brief search:

1. cumque
2. itaque (not really a conjunction, but I'll include it)
3. namque
4. sicutque (one attestation in Siculus, *Eclogae* 6.46)
5. utque

None of the corresponding pairs (*cunc*, *itac*, *nanc*, *sicuc*, *uc*) occurs in a classical corpus, even though some (especially *at*/*ut*) seem pretty exact equivalents.

In short: **this substitution does not appear to occur in any other words except *ac* and *nec* (EDIT) and *donec***.

Comment: I am unclear on whether *donec* < *donique* is a false etymology or not. L&S's "donique = donicum" seems pretty cryptic...

Comment: I looked up *donec* in de Vaan but he doesn't list it at all, unless I somehow missed it.

Comment: Oh, it's under a different heading (p. 161). He derives *dōnec* from a form * dō-ne-kwe, and *dōnicum* from * dō-ne-kwom, but then says in the next sentence that "Lat. *dōni/eque* is probably a recent remake on the model of *nec/neque*". Not sure why the latter statement, but it does look like the *-c* of *dōnec* is from *-que*.