# Why is there a Q in SPQR?

Tags: conjunction, abbreviations

The abbreviation SPQR stands for *Senatus PopulusQue Romanus*. Why is the Q included, as there are only three words? Why isn't it just SPR? Or does SPQR stand for something else?

Comment: **MODERATOR NOTICE:** This is not a real question! It is a place-holder for the example question on the [tour] page. As such the question and both answers are entirely contrived to fit the limited space and formatting restrictions. Please don't answer or edit this question and its answers directly. If you have any input please participate in [this meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/365/12).

Comment: Note that this content is heavily trimmed from [Why is the Roman acronym SPQR and not SPR?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5045/12).

Answer (score 3):

The enclitic *-que* was treated much like a word. This is most evident in the way Ovid handles quotes, where *-que* is outside a quote but the word it's attached to is inside. There are few other ancient abbreviations with *-que*, if any, so it's difficult to compare.

Comment: For a concrete example, consider *Metamorphoses* V.414: "*adgnovitque deam 'ne' c 'longius ibitis!' inquit*" which uses *-c* instead of *-que*.

Answer (score 3):

We definitely know that SPQR refers to *senatus populusque Romanus* and not something else. This text is inscribed in full in the temple of Saturn and arch of Titus in Rome. It's hard to say whether the abbreviation is systematic or an arbitrary choice that happened to stick.